# Output multiple strings across different lines in ion-select tag

Tags: ionic-framework

I have 3 strings I want to output within the [ion-select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select) tag and the two of them must be in one line while the third string should be in another line. How should I go about doing this?

My HTML code:

```
  <ion-select class="ag-max-width"  (ionChange)="clickedslide($event)" placeholder="List of Consumer No." slot="end"
    mode="ios">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let knolist of knoList ; let i=index" [value]="i">
        {{knolist.kno}} ({{knolist.name}})                                                                
        {{knolist.addr}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

I have tried to using this css to make the strings go to different lines but its not working correctly

```
  .alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Please make your questions little more clear. Provide enough sample data, try to define the input and output clearer. Mention your attempts and the difficulties that you are facing to achieve the target.

Comment: Edited my question. Hopefully its more clear now @Nitheesh

Comment: if you need to display more information on more than one line, why don't you use a modal instead ? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal you can still pass data from there.

Comment: Have you tried a good ol' fashioned BR tag? 
`<ion-select-option *ngFor="let knolist of knoList ; let i=index" [value]="i">
 {{knolist.kno}} ({{knolist.name}})  <br><br>                                                              
 {{knolist.addr}}
  </ion-select-option>`